# Can I restore a Litecoin wallet with Public / Secret?

Tags: litecoin, private-key, hash, public-key, litecoin-qt

I apogolize if this has been asked, I have spent several hours trying to figure this out.

I found an old document of my with a **Litecoin Public and Secret key**.

- I **don't** have a `*.dat` file, is this a problem?
- I **do have** The Public key is `34` characters
- I **do have** The Private key is `51` characters
- I am using Litecoin Core Qt - Wallet (Which I used in 2015).
- The blockchain is downloaded (About 10GB), yet it just sits here
- Q1: Do all I supply is my private key?
- Q2: Is there a way to check balance with any of my keys, or conversions below?
- Q3: Are coins lost if you don't have the `.dat` file anymore?

---

In the Application, I can run the `Debug > Console` and run:

```
# (This is a fake address, but it's in this format)
importprivkey "6vpo4RFWLcGhk4VsdFk34K3243K3kdsk4k23k32kAkasdkewkwe" "Jesse"`
```

The above gives me a "Receivable" key under `Receiving Address` which is identical to my Public key (`34 characters`).

I used some Online Bitcoin tools to convert the `Public key`, I thought I might need to run importpubkey, key it's must be there since it's visible in my `Receiving Address`?

- I'm not sure what for but I was able to get:
- (**a**) (Address to Hash): `40` character hash
- (**b**) (Hash to 160 Address Bitcoin, using **a**): `34` characters
- (**c**) (Pubkey to Hash, using **a**): `40` characters

I'm not sure what all this means, this is terribly confusing I don't remember how I did this in the past. If anyone could give me a plain answer I'd really appreciate it and I'll be sure to tick it off as correct and settle the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is `importprivkey`. The software will handle everything else. Everything else it needs can be derived from the private key, and it will do so when you give it a private key.